# Dialog box crashes Android service

Tags: android, service, popup

**CODE**

```
         this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
              android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, 
              true, new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                  Toast.makeText(audioServices.this, "Working..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  //dispVC();
                  dialog = new Dialog(audioServices.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.vc);

                    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                      dialog.show();
                  //System.out.println("Works!");
                }
            });
```

This is the [logcat](http://pastebin.com/ZLmpMzGF).
Note - `01-09 17:54:43.137: E/AndroidRuntime(7210):     at com.torcellite.popupvc.audioServices$1.onChange(audioServices.java:59)`

Line 59 is `dialog.show();`

**---EDIT---**

So, I changed the code to this.

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(audioServices.this, vcDialog.class);
                    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    audioServices.this.startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

My app still crashes. This is the [logcat](http://pastebin.com/3p1Z9HvY).

Comment: no need to change activity theme to dialog just do as i say and you are done.

Comment: i think it's not possible  to show dialog from service you will need to start an transparent Activity from service

Comment: what is audioService ?? activity or service??

Comment: The logcat you linked to doesn't exist (second one)

Comment: @RaghavSood Sorry, typo. Try again.

Comment: The logcat doesn't match your code. Try running the code again and see if you still get an exception.

Comment: @RaghavSood I've uploaded the new logcat - http://pastebin.com/tCjZgUp0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service doesn't have  any UI elements, so can't show a dialog box. A dialog can only be added from an Activity context. You can either call an activity that does have a UI, with a dialog theme if you'd like or it might be better to create a notification which is the preferred option for Android alerts.

**EDIT**

Based on your new code, your intent is fine. Instead add the following to your manifest in the application tag:

```
<activity android:name=".vcDialog" />
```

Comment: we can also add UI elements to dialog by setting up a layout to it.

Comment: We can do that, yes. However, a dialog can only be created when using an Activity context. A non ui Context like a service or broadcast receiver will not work.

Comment: he has not put all his code.May be his activity's name is audioService.

Comment: @RaghavSood I made an activity and called it from the service. Still crashes. Here's the logcat - http://pastebin.com/3p1Z9HvY

Line 43 is the code for starting the activity.

Comment: @Neurenor No, Raghav is right. audioService is a service and not an activity.

Comment: ohh.than you have to pass activity context.

Comment: and after you pass activity context you won't be able to show dialog.because you can not add the UI element to dialog before you called .show() method.please check it.

Comment: @Neurenor I changed my approach. I decided to call an activity instead. I'm still experiencing problems though. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity context instead of context of Service. Also instead of dialog use DialogFragments.

Answer (score -1):

```
dialogIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
dialogIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

put these lines instead of

```
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

line
and try calling activity like this

```
this.getApplicationContext().startActivity(dialogIntent)
```

Comment: have you added the Multiple_task flag?

Comment: Yeah, I replaced your snippet with mine.